# AFNetworking Background Session KVO Error

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, afnetworking-3

Occassionally my app crashes upon launch.

It seems to be related to failed background NSURL Session Activity. This message appears fairly consistently in the Crashlytics log:

```
_block_invoke line 233 $ Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service"
```

I'm stumped as to how to debug this issue in xCode since I haven't been able to cause it to happen while my test device is connected to my computer.

I am not using KVO in my app; maybe this is an issue with AFNetworking itself?

Here is the crash message that Crashlytics reports:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
An instance 0x14f97ef00 of class __NSCFBackgroundDataTask was deallocated while 
key value observers were still registered with it. 
Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x14f97f320> ( <NSKeyValueObservance 0x14f841ea0: Observer: 0x14e777340, Key path: countOfBytesReceived, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x14e650010> <NSKeyValueObservance 0x14e6e1770: Observer: 0x14e777340, Key path: countOfBytesExpectedToReceive, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x14f81c090> <NSKeyValueObservance 0x14f80e030: Observer: 0x14e777340, Key path: countOfBytesSent, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x14f97e880> <NSKeyValueObservance 0x14e5ca9c0: Observer: 0x14e777340, Key path: countOfBytesExpectedToSend, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x14f97cf20> )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this might be caused by having duplicate GET requests.

Comment: See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3380, that might help you.

Comment: I think this will be fixed when they release AFNetworking 3.1.1 (3.1.0 is the current version.)  We're going to backport this fix:  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/ff228fad3addd141cc668891b6c3bb9b1b1c4271.patch

Comment: Adding this in case it helps others find this SO question

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3380

I think this will be fixed when they release AFNetworking 3.1.1 (3.1.0 is the current version.)

Backporting https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/ff228fad3addd141cc668891b6c3bb9b1b1c4271.patch fixed this problem for me.

Adding this in case it helps others find this question

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fdcb4d099f0 of class __NSCFBackgroundDataTask was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x60000002da80> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60000005b2d0: Observer: 0x600000283110, Key path: countOfBytesReceived, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000005b300>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60000005b660: Observer: 0x600000283110, Key path: countOfBytesExpectedToReceive, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000005b690>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60000005b870: Observer: 0x600000283110, Key path: countOfBytesSent, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000005b8a0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60000005ba20: Observer: 0x600000283110, Key path: countOfBytesExpectedToSend, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000005ba50>
```